# Suppose a classroom has 25 students seated in desks in a square 5 × 5 array.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

The teacher wants to alter the seating by having every student move to an adjacent seat (just ahead, just behind, on the left, or on the right). Show that such a move is impossible.

I just want to make sure that I understand what this question is asking.

This question is (in subtle terms) asking you to construct a hamilton circuit and then asking you to show that it's impossible correct?

Comment: Could you explain why such a move entails a hamiltonian circuit?

Comment: A hamiltonian circuit would prove the existence of such a move. However the move does not need to be a hamiltonian circuit, rather it could be a collection of hamiltonian circuits. Consider a 2x4 array with first row: 1234 and second row: 5678. A possible move would be to cycle the students 1256 and cycle the students 3478. This is not 1 hamiltonian circuit, but 2 different circuits.

Answer (score 3):

Paint the desks black and white as if it was a chessboard. There will be $13$ black and $12$ white desks. After a move, if it existed, every student would move from a black desk to a white desk and vice versa. This cannot happen as it would suddenly require $13$ white desks.

Comment: Oh so i could think of this as bipartite. And since there are an odd number of vertices (25). It's impossible to alter the seating to get it the way the teacher wants correct?